# Win10 media conversion while copying to Android

Tags: windows-10, android, file-transfer

On Win10 when I copy a FLAC file to my Android device, Win10 asks me if I want to convert this file on the fly.
If I press ok, it will encode the FLAC file to WMA before copying.
Is there any config to this process?
Is it possible to convert to MP3 for example instead of WMA?

Comment: Easier to just convert it using 3rd party software before copying it. Windows 10 by default wants to use its own encoder which is wma, if Microsoft wanted to use mp3, they would have to pay for a license fee for each installation of Windows. http://mp3licensing.com/about/fhg.html

Comment: This will only happen if the media is connected as MTP. If possible, change the connection mode to USB mass storage.